# I want to download torrent files to a fashdrive attached to modem or router (local server ) by initiating the download from the mobile device

Tags: downloading, ftp, torrents

I want to download torrent files from my mobile but since I don't have enough storage I want the files to be downloaded to my local server (the flashdrive/pendrive attached to my modem which can be accessed wirelessly), Is there a way to do this?

I don't want my laptop running continuously for downloading torrent files, instead I would like to use my mobile phone but the problem is that I have very limited storage in my android device. Is there a way to download to a remote Pendrive or storage device attached to my modem or router?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think that a Bittorrent app exists that can work the way you want. In my opinion you should better get yourself a Raspberry Pi or a similar tiny computer. Those devices require very little power and can be configured very flexible if you are willing to learn Linux. The chance is high that there is already a Bittorrent client for Linux that can be controlled using an Android app.